# AWS Amplify config file

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I use Angular and Amplify. 
When I use generated config object (the one copied to src with fields like 'aws_cognito_identity_pool_id', 'aws_user_pools_id') I am able to autheticate using   component.

But when I provide my own config object:

```
export const awsConfig = {
  Auth: {
    // REQUIRED - Amazon Cognito Identity Pool ID
    identityPoolId: 'eu-west-1:XXX48cXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-2572XXXXX2XX',
    // REQUIRED - Amazon Cognito Region
    region: 'eu-west-1',
    // OPTIONAL - Amazon Cognito User Pool ID
    userPoolId: 'eu-west-1_XXXSXXXX',
    // OPTIONAL - Amazon Cognito Web Client ID
    userPoolWebClientId: 'XXXXoefiXXXXomXXXjq4XXX',
  },
  API: {
    endpoints: [
      {
        name: 'endpointDAO',
        endpoint: `https://api.my-custom-cloudfront-domain.com`
      },
      {
        name: 'MyCustomCloudFrontApi',
        endpoint: 'https://api.my-custom-cloudfront-domain.com',
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I get an error

```
1 validation error detected: Value at 'clientId' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: [\w+]+
```

I read that it's usually caused by providing user pool id instead identity pool but I think that's not the case here.

What I do wrong?

Comment: Forgot about the magic factor. After taking some break everything worked properly. Probably some cache stuff.